# Closed Sets VS. Complete Sets

Tags: real-analysis, cauchy-sequences

Let $(X,d)$ be a metric space. If   $K⊆X$, and $K$
 is a closed set. Does that mean any Cauchy sequence in $K$ converges in $K$?

If no, could someone give an example?

If yes, then what is the difference between complete sets and closed sets?

Comment: No. Take $(\mathbb Q,d)$. Then $\mathbb Q$ is closed but not every Cauchy sequence converges. E.g take a sequence $(x_n)$ in $\mathbb Q$ converging in $\mathbb R$ to $\pi\notin\mathbb Q$.

Comment: Great, What about if the inclusion is strictly?

Comment: My example shows that the case will not be changed if the inclusion is strict. $(-\sqrt11,\sqrt11)$ is closed in $\mathbb Q$ but you can let $x_n\in(-\sqrt11,\sqrt11)$

Comment: Aha, Thank you so much.

Comment: If $(X,d)$ is complete metric space, and $K\subseteq X$ is closed in $X$, then it is complete. [Proof](http://www.planetmath.org/AClosedSubsetOfACompleteMetricSpaceIsComplete).

Comment: Also, complete subspace of _any_ metric space is closed. When you combine with my previous comment, if $(X,d)$ is complete, closed subsets are the same as complete subspaces.

Comment: @Ennar  thank you so much Ennar.

Answer (score 2):

The rationals are closed in the rationals, but obviously not complete. For strict inclusion, take $\mathbb{Q} \cap [0,1]$ in $\mathbb{Q}$. Also not complete, but closed.

Incidentally, complete implies closed. Just look at limit points and sequences.

Comment: Great, What about if the inclusion is strictly?